# Missing staticfiles manifest entry in Django deployment using Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles, static-files, collectstatic

I am trying to deploy my webapp to heroku. I am using Django and the following is most of my settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for blog project on Heroku. For more info, see:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import dj_database_url
import raven

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Disable Django's own staticfiles handling in favour of WhiteNoise, for
    # greater consistency between gunicorn and `./manage.py runserver`. See:
    # http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blogapp',
    'homeapp',
    'nimfksapp',
    'omniclipapp',

    #Heroku Sentry
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'
   
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'
    
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'live-static', 'static-root')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "live-static", "media-root")

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

When running `collectstatic` locally the static files get collected fine and are served up on the web page. When I deploy the app to heroku (which automatically runs the `collectstatic` command for me) it throws up an "Internal Server Error (500)". I followed a recommendation on a similar SO page and added a sentry to the app through heroku and got a clearer error message:

> ValueError/nimfks/ errorMissing staticfiles manifest entry for...

I tried changing (and removing) the `STATICFILES_STORAGE` without success. Removing it got me past the error but trying to display the actual static file (in this case an image) didnt work i.e. it wasnt loading.

I also tried changing the static settings to use `PROJECT_ROOT` instead of `BASE_DIR` and a lot of different configurations, all of which didnt work.

Am I missing something here? I cant seem to find an answer in the similar questions asked on SO.

**EDIT**

**Answer**:

Embarrasing as it is I want to keep this up since it might help someone else struggling with this. Issue in my case was that I was using `.PNG` in my html file instead of `.png` which was the real file extension. Didn't realize this was case sensitive. The real solution to this problem was essentially just having a sentry running that will catch these types of errors (see [sentry docs](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sentry)). This is my final version of my static settings in the settings.py file:

```
import os
import dj_database_url
import raven

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
]

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Answer (score -4):

Try to comment the line
    **'django.contrib.staticfiles',**
inside INSTALLED_APPS